# pgfmolbio: Undefined control sequence \pmbchromatogram

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I was trying to make a chromatogram today using `pgfmolbio` using pdfTeX from TeX Live 2013.

The code I was using is:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[chromatogram]{pgfmolbio}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\pmbchromatogram{seq.scf}
\end{document}
```

The code gives me following error:

```
./figures-1.tex:5: Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \pmbchromatogram
                {seq.scf}
```

I tried my best to follow the manual page. However, even if I load the `convert` module, the same error message still occurs. I saw `Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.` in the log. Could this be the source of the problem?

edit:

I also tried run the file with `luatex` after read Paul's comment. It gives me the following result:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013061817 (rev 4627) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./figures-1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                {article}
?
```

edit:

Here is the result from `lualatex`.

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013061817 (rev 4627) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./figures-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/pgfmolbio/pgfmolbio.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-modutils.s
ty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-loader.sty

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-compat.sty
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.loader.lua)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/modutils.lua))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/lualibs/lualibs.lua)
! LuaTeX error ...xlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/modutils.lua:57: m
odule 'pgfmolbio' not found:
    no field package.preload['pgfmolbio']
    [luatexbase.loader] Search failed
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'pgfmolbio'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'pgfmolbio'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ...xlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/modutils.lua:57: in function 're
quire_module'
    [string "\directlua "]:1: in main chunk.
\lltxb@requirelua ...xluaescapestring {#2}" \fi )}

l.44 \fi
```

The log file is attached:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) (format=pdflatex 2013.7.20)  29 JUL 2013 23:36
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**figures-1.tex
(./figures-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/pgfmolbio/pgfmolbio.sty
Package: pgfmolbio 2012/10/01 v0.2 Molecular biology graphs with TikZ

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def
File: dvipsnam.def 1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/svgnam.def
File: svgnam.def 2007/01/21 v2.11 Predefined colors according to SVG 1.1 (UK)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box26
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
))
Package: pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen105
\pgf@y=\dimen106
\pgf@xa=\dimen107
\pgf@ya=\dimen108
\pgf@xb=\dimen109
\pgf@yb=\dimen110
\pgf@xc=\dimen111
\pgf@yc=\dimen112
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count88
\c@pgf@countb=\count89
\c@pgf@countc=\count90
\c@pgf@countd=\count91

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Package pgfsys Info: Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def on input line 900.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2009/05/22  (rcs-revision 1.26)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2008/05/19  (rcs-revision 1.10)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count92
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count93
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen113
\pgfmath@count=\count94
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks19
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks20
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks21
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count95
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2010/04/09  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen114
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen115
\pgf@picminy=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen117
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen118
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen121
\pgf@xx=\dimen122
\pgf@xy=\dimen123
\pgf@yx=\dimen124
\pgf@yy=\dimen125
\pgf@zx=\dimen126
\pgf@zy=\dimen127
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2010/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen128
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen129
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen130
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen131
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2010/09/08  (rcs-revision 1.34)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count96
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen132
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2009/06/10  (rcs-revision 1.11)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen133
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen134
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen135
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2008/04/23  (rcs-revision 1.11)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2008/11/23  (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgf@max=\dimen136
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count97
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2010/03/25  (rcs-revision 1.16)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2010/09/01  (rcs-revision 1.17)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2010/08/27  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2008/01/17  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2009/07/02  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2010/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2010/10/22  (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen137
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen138
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen139
\pgffor@skip=\dimen140
\pgffor@stack=\toks22
\pgffor@toks=\toks23
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2010/05/31 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count98
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen141
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen142
\tikz@lasty=\dimen143
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen144
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen145
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen146
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen147
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@tempbox=\box34
\tikztreelevel=\count99
\tikznumberofchildren=\count100
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count101
\tikz@fig@count=\count102

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2010/08/24  (rcs-revision 1.4)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count103
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count104
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count105
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count106

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex 2008/10/06 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarysvg.path.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarysvg.path.code.tex 2009/01/24 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibrarysvg.pat
h.code.tex
File: pgflibrarysvg.path.code.tex 2009/01/24 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.6)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleparser.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmoduleparser.code.tex 2009/01/12 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
)
\pgf@lib@svg@last@x=\dimen148
\pgf@lib@svg@last@y=\dimen149
\pgf@lib@svg@last@c@x=\dimen150
\pgf@lib@svg@last@c@y=\dimen151
\pgf@lib@svg@count=\count107
\pgf@lib@svg@max@num=\count108
))
\@pmb@toksa=\toks24
\@pmb@toksb=\toks25

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/pgfmolbio/pgfmolbio.chromatogr
am.tex
File: pgfmolbio.chromatogram.tex 2012/10/01 v0.2 SCF chromatograms
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/pgfmolbio/pgfmolbio.convert.te
x
File: pgfmolbio.convert.tex 2012/10/01 v0.2 pgfmolbio graph conversion
)) (./figures-1.aux)
\openout1 = `figures-1.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count109
\scratchdimen=\dimen152
\scratchbox=\box35
\nofMPsegments=\count110
\nofMParguments=\count111
\everyMPshowfont=\toks26
\MPscratchCnt=\count112
\MPscratchDim=\dimen153
\MPnumerator=\count113
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count114
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks27
) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \pmbchromatogram
                    {seq.scf}
? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10116 strings out of 493311
 198299 string characters out of 6137850
 242783 words of memory out of 5000000
 13376 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 63i,0n,57p,456b,83s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 3 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: The `pgfmolbio` package needs the `luatex` engine!

Comment: Is it means I need to compile the `figures-1.tex` with `luatex`?

Comment: Yes (look at p.44 of the `pgfmolbio` manual).

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! Have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: @Mys_721tx As others comment, the key features of `mgfmolbio` require LuaTeX, but the package does not really issue suitable warning/error messages about this. However, LuaTeX was updated for TeX Live 2013 in a way that requires changes to module loading, and `pgfmolbio` hasn't been modified to reflect that. So with your installation I suspect this isn't going to work. I suggest a bug report to the package author.

Comment: @JosephWright I checked my texmf-dist and found out that the file `pgfmolbio.lua` is actually missing. I got the package from CTAN. However, it still has some errors that are not part of the package loading.

Comment: Within TeXLive 2013 and 2012, `pgfmolbio.lua` is only in `.../texmf-dist/doc/lualatex/pgfmolbio/pgfmolbio.lua`.

Comment: @JosephWright I wrote to Wolfgang and he replied. The v 0.21 on CTAN works now.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I don't think `lualatex` can find it. However, if I put all files from `pgfmolbio` under the same directory, `lualatex` can find every files it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the missing `pgfmolbio.lua` is a part of the problem. However, this can be solved by putting all the files from `pgfmolbio` package to the `.` directory of the tex file I was trying to compile. However, a bug report should be made to Tex Live.

The compatibility problem has been solved by Wolfgang himself. The update has been reflected on CRAN.